# Why does Google Earth Pro project these shapefiles correctly and QGIS does not?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, google-earth

[I have 2 shapefiles which you can find here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-FZAHduEvuTYVpQWDllU09zdG8)

I made neither of them they were both given to me.  Their .prj files are:

One that projects correctly in both programs

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_10N",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-123.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

One that projects correctly only in Google Earth Pro

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_10N",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",1640416.666666667],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-123.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]
```

they are supposed to overlap like so
[image: they are supposed to overlap like so]

But in QGIS (2.8.9-Wien) they are far apart

Comment: Also see if WKID EPSG::4410 is supported. That's a USFoot UTM-based projcs.

Comment: @mkennedy but based on NAD27. EPSG:4430 is based on NAD83, Both are included in QGIS 2.18.11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have almost the same projection in both map. The difference between them is the  CRS's unit. You need to create a custom CRS in `Settings / Custom CRS` using this proj4 setting:

```
+proj=utm +zone=10 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs
```

[image]

After this, set new CRS in grid layer on properties window:

[image]

It should work:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Datum are different, the top is in meters and the second in US ft (1 m = 3.2808333333465 ft) - Therefore the data should not sit exactly on top.
...it may also be due to the False Eastings which are both different, this will place the projection tangent (the point which the projection bisects the hemisphere) differently and cause a slight distortion.
By converting the data to the same coordinate system with the same vertical units the data sits perfectly.

Comment: It's not the datum, but the **units**  of the projection. As a side effect, the False Easting in the WKT definition is in the projection units, while in the PROJ.4 definition would be always in meters.